# Is there a similar function to COALESCE for empty string in AS400

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange

```
SELECT COALESCE(value, 'M') 
  FROM MyTable
```

In case the value is null the returned value will be set to "M"

Is there a similar function as COALESCE in case value is an empty string?

IBM i Version: 7.1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `NULLIF()`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(NULLIF(value, ''), 'M')
FROM [My Table]
```

Answer (score 6):

The DB2 database [appears to support COALESCE](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_10.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_bif_coalesce.html).  But in any case, `COALESCE` would only work for replacing `NULL`, not empty string.  One option here would be to just use a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN value <> '' THEN value ELSE 'M' END AS value
FROM [My Table];
```

If you want to handle both `NULL` and empty string together, then use this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN COALESCE(value, '') <> '' THEN value ELSE 'M' END AS value
FROM [My Table];
```

Comment: I think the case is the right answer, but the OP is trying to coalesce an empty string instead of null.

Comment: My version does support COALESCE

Answer (score 1):

No.

Just use a CASE expression, assuming value could be NULL or empty, check for NULL first.

```
case
  when value is NULL then 'M'
  when value = '' then 'M'
  else value
end as newValue
```

Comment: How about `CASE WHEN COALESCE(value, '') = '' THEN 'M'` ?

Comment: Case _expression_!

Comment: I always find it clearer to group the two when statements into a single one.  It makes it more obvious that both of them do the same thing (IE: when value is NULL or value = ' ' then 'M'